# im learning programming on my own and this code is not printing "correct"

Tags: python, user-input

I want the user to put two numbers and put the answer and the software to print correct if he had the right answer but it keeps printing `wrong`

```py
x = input("num1: ")
y = input("num2: ")
z = input ("num1 + num2: ")

results = float(x) + float(y)
if z == results:
    print("correct")
else :
    print("wrong")
```

Comment: A string is never equal to a float. But also for float only this may not work in all cases due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 4):

`input` returns `str` type.
`float(x)` and `float(y)` are for converting `str` to `float`.
So you need same thing for `z`.

Comparing `str` and `float` always results `False`(in this example, `'3.0' != 3.0`).

```py
x = input("num1: ")
y = input("num2: ")
z = float(input("num1 + num2: "))

results = float(x) + float(y)
if z == results:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

output:

```
num1: 1
num2: 2
num1 + num2: 3
correct
```